# Javascript regular expression that matches only JavaScript-style numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to create a javascript regular expression that matches only valid Javascript-style numbers.  More requirements include support for an optional minus or plus sign in front of the number, the decimal dot and exponent notations such as 1e-4 or 1E4, and again with an optional sign in front of the exponent.

The expression can accept digits in front or after the dot, but the number cannot be just a dot. Such as .2 and 2. are valid, but not just the dot.

Ideally the expression is contained in /^...$/; format.

I got a few of the items, but my expression should be able to pass valid javascript values such as .5, -.5 or +5

```
function validNumber(number) {
    var regexNum = /^-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?$/; 
    return regexNum.test(number);
}

console.log(validNumber("0.0001")); // true
console.log(validNumber("-5")); // true
console.log(validNumber("0.3425")); // true
console.log(validNumber("1e-4")); // true
console.log(validNumber("1E-4")); // true
console.log(validNumber("1Ee-4")); // false
console.log(validNumber("-4.34")); // true
console.log(validNumber("Test123")); // false
console.log(validNumber("+-2")); // false
console.log(validNumber("5.")); // true
console.log(validNumber(".")); // false
console.log(validNumber(".5")); // Should be true, but passes as false
console.log(validNumber("-.5")); // Should be true, but passes as false
console.log(validNumber("+5"));  // Should be true, but passes as false
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try `/^[+-]?\d*\.?\d+(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?$/`

Comment: You can test your regular expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/4Req7C/1), I've copied your tests here

Comment: `alert(0x5f + 0b10101)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
/^[-+]?(?:\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ne6wOb/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[-+]?` - an optional `+` or `-` sign
- `(?:\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)` - either of the two sequences:

  - `\.[0-9]+` - a dot and 1+ digits
  - `|` - or
  - `[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?` - 1+ digits, then an optional sequence of a `.` followed with 0+ digits
- `(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?` - an optional exponent part:

  - `[eE]` - an `e` or `E`
  - `[-+]?` - an optional plus or minus
  - `[0-9]+` - 1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.

```js
var regexNum = /^[-+]?(?:\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)(?:[eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$/;

function validNumber(number) {
    return regexNum.test(number);
}

console.log("0.0001", validNumber("0.0001")); // true
console.log("-5", validNumber("-5")); // true
console.log("0.3425", validNumber("0.3425")); // true
console.log("1e-4", validNumber("1e-4")); // true
console.log("1E-4", validNumber("1E-4")); // true
console.log("1Ee-4", validNumber("1Ee-4")); // false
console.log("-4.34", validNumber("-4.34")); // true
console.log("Test123", validNumber("Test123")); // false
console.log("+-2", validNumber("+-2")); // false
console.log("5.", validNumber("5.")); // true
console.log(".", validNumber(".")); // false
console.log(".5", validNumber(".5")); // Should be true, but passes as false
console.log("-.5", validNumber("-.5")); // Should be true, but passes as false
console.log("+5", validNumber("+5"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below regex?

var pattern = new RegExp("(^([-|+]?)([0-9]{0,12}?)(\.)([0-9]){0,12}$)|(^([-|+]?)([0-9]){0,12}$)");